# Eclipse: Android: Failed to load dx.jar

Tags: android, eclipse

Windows 10 (64 bit), Eclipse Oxygen.

I success build my Android project.
But when I try to run I get error:

```
[2018-09-06 11:17:36 - Dex Loader] Failed to load d:\Programs\android-sdk-eclipse\build-tools\28.0.2\lib\dx.jar
[2018-09-06 11:17:36 - factura] Unknown error: Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder!
```

In folder `d:\Programs\android-sdk-eclipse\build-tools\28.0.2\lib` has file `dx.jar`

[image]

In Eclise, the SDK location is:

```
d:\Programs\android-sdk-eclipse\
```

Comment: Why are you still using eclipse btw

Comment: It's old project that was write before 5 years on Eclipse.

Comment: you can still import it in Android Studio

Comment: OK, but it will take a lot of time. The project is big.